# find a common subgraph

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

I am trying to find to get the common subgraph given two graphs.
If I have 2 graphs G1=(v1,e1) and G2=(v2,e2) i must find the common subgraf G=(V,E) such as to any another common subgraph of G1 and G2 mustn't contain more then cardinal of E arris.

Given that Graph 1 is

A - B

A - C

B - D

D - E

Graph 2 is

A - B

A - E

B - D

Than the algorithm should return

A - B

B - D

Can you help me with an algorithm which tells me what steps to attend?
Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong - but it seems you are looking for the largest common subset of edges. Is that correct?

Comment: Home work due in for tomorrow or can you leave it with us?

Answer (score 3):

You are not describing your problem formally, but from your example<sup>1</sup>, it seems you are looking for a largest common subset of *edges*.

To achieve it - you simply need the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) of E1 and E2.

**Proof:**

**(->)** Assume `(a,b)` is in `E1 [intersection] E2`. By definition of set intersection - it is common to both E1 and E2 - and thus to G1 and G2 as well.

**(<-)** Assume `(a,b)` is common to G1 and G2 - then `(a,b)` is in `E1` and  `(a,b)` is in `E2` - from definition of intersection, `(a,b)` is in `E1 [intersection] E2`

---

(1) I conclude that because `(A,C)` is not "common", and yet `(A,B)` is in the subgraph - meaning this is not a restriction of finding a subset of vertices that can create the desired subgraph (because then `A` should have been excluded from the result).